# In Magento 2.4.x, How to remove the breadcrumb link and add custom class?

Tags: magento2, xml, breadcrumbs

In Magento 2.4.x, I want to add the breadcrumb without a link and need to add a custom class for that. How to add that?

Here is my XML code.

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Online Shop</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Online Shop</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Online Shop</item>
                <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
<!--Here I need to remove the link for this item and need to add a class-->
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Product Category</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Category</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin>Catalog>Categories.

Then go to "Select your category tree".

Then go to "Design tab"

And on Layout Update XML field add

> <referenceContainer name="breadcrumbs" remove="true/>"